# How can I clear out unneeded files - like cache, tmp et al?

Tags: applications, cache, temp-files

Are there any Bleachbit like software for Android?
Software that cleanes all the tmp, cache, unneded files..

Comment: I wouldn't assume that this community is familiar with Bleachbit. I'm not. Rather than asking for an app, you'll probably have better luck here if you ask for help solving a particular problem. It sounds like you're trying to clean out files. To what end? On what schedule? If you edit your question to make it clear what you're trying to do, I'm sure the community can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This app cleaners a lot of the cache http://www.appbrain.com/app/android-assistant(14-features)/com.advancedprocessmanager# although doesn't automatically detected unneeded files it will let you delete them manually.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I can tell, Android doesn't keep around a lot of cached files for the OS.  Your phone's recovery mode should also have a "Clear cache" option that would do the trick, and you can clear individual app caches from `Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications`.

Answer (score 0):

Titanium Backup has an option to look for dalvik-cache that is not needed, but only the paid version cleans it up. Instead, you can use Ghost-commander, in root mode go to **/data/dalvik-cache**, select remount command, and select and delete all you want in that directory, restart device and it will rebuild the cache, and use up less memory.

For application cache and data, you can go to settings, applications, and sort by size to see what is taking the most space, clear its cache, uninstall, etc.